# Function1 not working with Covariant and Contravariant arguments

Tags: scala

Why following code gives error. I suppose `Function1` is of type `[-A,+A]`

```
scala> class CSuper
defined class CSuper

scala> class CBase extends CSuper
defined class CBase

scala> class CSub extends CBase
defined class CSub

scala> val f:Function1[CBase,CBase] = (c:CBase) => new CBase
f: CBase => CBase = $$Lambda$1284/2064513681@642f8b7f

scala> val f1:Function1[-CBase,+CBase] = (c:CBase) => new CBase
<console>:1: error: identifier expected but ',' found.
val f1:Function1[-CBase,+CBase] = (c:CBase) => new CBase
                       ^

scala>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot specify covariance / contravariance when using a generic, only when defining it. The `Function1` generic is already defined as 
`trait Function1[-T1, +R]`, there is no need for you to specify this.

Comment: OK. So correct way is `scala> val f1:Function1[CBase,CBase]= (c:CSuper) => new CSub`

Comment: If this is what you want, most likely you do not have to write `Function1` at all, just write `val f1 = (c: CSuper) => new CSub`. The covariance / contravariance will make sure the function is usable as appropriate, even when something expects to receive `(CBase) => CBase`.

Comment: So if I use `(c:CSuper)=>...`, the compiler will decide covariance or contravariance w.r.t. `CSuper`?